# MVC 3 ASP.NET: Gridview based on textbox value in ASP.NETMVC 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a textbox which will contain phone numbers. I need to fill a grid view with the name and address of owner of phone number. I need that gridview to be initially hidden and then displayed with the data. I use MVC 3, Razor and C#. I'm beginner, can reference some example?. God bless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="myGridContainer">
 <!-- your grid lives here -->
</div>
<input id="myButton" type="button" value="Show/Hide"/>

$(document).ready(
function(){

$('#myButton').click(function(){
 $('#myGridContainer').toggle();
}
}
);
```

Above pseudocode might help you. If you are not comfortable with plain HTML,CSS and JavaScript, I would recommend brushing up on that first. It will help you understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have a button `click` handler and write a code to show the grid in the handler.

```
$('buttonSelector').click(function(){
    $('gridSelector').show();
});
```

And make sure the grid is hidden through css on page load. Apply the below class on the grid which will hide it initially on page load.

```
.hide{
   display:none;
}
```

If you have a id or any class on the button you can select the button using its id or classname.

`$('#buttonId)` or `$('.buttonClassName)`

To select the grid have some class on the grid and select it as below.

`$('.gridClassName')`

Comment: sorry I am beginner, you could illustrate with an example?

Comment: thank you very much friend, you know some example on the web about this?